# How to create a complex legend in qgis?

Tags: qgis, legend

I would need to create a complex legend divided into many sub-sections that does not correspond to different layers but to different rule-based styling objects. It seems to me that this possibility is not supported by the legend items in print composer, how can I overcome this problem?

p.s. the images refer to a part (some layers) of the entire legend

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you share an excerpt or example of the atrribute table that you want to organize in that way?